# Java file access

Tags: java

At the moment, in my java program, I am accessing a file that is in the project folder. When I'm loading the file its path is "./src/package/package/file.txt". When I build the program into an executable it dosen't work.

I would prefer the files to be outside of the .jar, but in the same folder, how would I got about this?

Samishal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Class.getResourceAsStream` to get the `InputStream`. It works for jar package too. It is not possible to access the file in jar file using `File` API directly.

```
InputStream ins = Class.getResourceAsStream("/gigadot/exp/resource.properties");
```

More details at http://blog.gigadot.net/2010/10/loading-classpath-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [relative path](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Absolutepathandrelativepath.htm) if they are in the same folder, such as `./file.txt`. That should carry over even with a compiled JAR.

Otherwise, if you're going to be using the same machine and are confident of the placement of the files, you *could* use an absolute path, however I don't recommend it.

Comment: @EJP I had that in my original answer but removed it because I wasn't sure if it was required in Java. Is the dot prefix required for same-directory?

Comment: Is it not possible to specify a relative path to the file in the same directoy as the .jar

Comment: @DavidB yeah, didnt work, maybe I'm not being clear, I need the file to be outside the .jar but in the same directory as the .jar

Comment: java may be loading several jars, each in different directory, so there is no easy way to create a path relative to one specific jar (possible, but will be difficult). However, in java path are relative to the directory where you executed your program from, so you can put your txt file into that directory and it should work.

Comment: @Samishalt Update your question with code and maybe a picture of your file structure.

Comment: @DavidB its ok managed to fix it, tried your code again and it worked beautifully, it was netbeans being an arse that cause it all thanks

Comment: @Samishalt No problem- if the answer fixed your issue, make sure to hit the green checkmark underneath the score to "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the relative path is relative to where your command prompt is when you execute the program, not from where the program lives.

You somehow need to tell the program where to find resources.  Most people use a .sh/.bat script to figure out where the script itself lives, and either pass -D flags or set the classpath based on that location.

as a note, I $0 gives you the script as it was run on the command line in linux (it could be relative or absolute), and you can use dirname from there to find it's directory, and alter the java command line.

in windows %~dp0 gives you the directory of the batch script which was run, and you can use that to form your java command line.